# Jenkins + Gradle + Artifactory: Couldn't read generated build info

Tags: jenkins, gradle, release, artifactory, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to push my artifacts to Artifactory with Jenkins Pipeline, which call Gradle tool.

I am following the examples published on GitHub:

- [Example1](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-pipeline-examples/gradle-example/Jenkinsfile)
- [Example2](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-pipeline-examples/gradle-example-ci-server/Jenkinsfile)

My Jenkins Pipeline script:

```
stage('Perform Gradle Release') {

    //ssh-agent required to perform GIT push (when tagging the branch on release)
    sshagent([git_credential]) {
        sh "./gradlew clean release unSnapshotVersion -Prelease.useAutomaticVersion=true -Prelease.releaseVersion=${release_version} -Prelease.newVersion=${development_version}"
    }

    // Create an Artifactory server instance
    def server = Artifactory.server('my-artifactory')

    // Create and set an Artifactory Gradle Build instance:
    def rtGradle = Artifactory.newGradleBuild()
    rtGradle.resolver server: server, repo: 'libs-release'
    rtGradle.deployer server: server, repo: 'libs-release-local'

    //Use Gradle Wrapper
    rtGradle.useWrapper = true

    //Creates buildinfo
    def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
    buildInfo.env.capture = true
    buildInfo.env.filter.addInclude("*")

    // Run Gradle:
    rtGradle.run rootDir: "./", buildFile: 'build.gradle', tasks: 'clean artifactoryPublish', buildInfo: buildInfo

    // Publish the build-info to Artifactory:
    server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo

}
```

My Gradle file is very light, I'm just using the plugin [Gradle Release Plugin](https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release) to perform gradle release.

When executing the pipeline, it fails with this message:

```
:artifactoryPublish

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 17.451 secs
ERROR: Couldn't read generated build info at : /tmp/generated.build.info4898776990575217114.json
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.model.Run$RunnerAbortedException
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.Utils.getGeneratedBuildInfo(Utils.java:188)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.ArtifactoryGradleBuild$Execution.run(ArtifactoryGradleBuild.java:127)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.ArtifactoryGradleBuild$Execution.run(ArtifactoryGradleBuild.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousStepExecution.start(AbstractSynchronousStepExecution.java:40)
...
Finished: FAILURE
```

When I check on the server, there is no such file /tmp/generated.build.info4898776990575217114.json (the user has of course permission to write to /tmp).

Thanks for your help.

[EDIT] It is weird, but I found some files named "buildInfo2408849984051060030.properties", containing the informations. The name is not the same, neither the format, and these files are stores on my Jenkins machine, not my slave executing the pipeline.

Comment: Jenkins Artifactory Plugin version 2.8.2 has some improvement related to your issue.
We changed the way we save the generated file and in addition, we added more informative logs.
The related commit can be found at https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info/commit/9180bb9ccc31a0217ff645221bccc93d6a2f603d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @tamir-hadad, it has indeed been fixed on 2.8.2.