# Maven + Jenkins + Artifactory

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

This is very similar to [Jenkins + Gradle + Artifactory: Couldn't read generated build info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849703/jenkins-gradle-artifactory-couldnt-read-generated-build-info) but apparently i violate a SO rule if i write this comment there so spawning a new question...

Using v2.8.2 of the artifactory plugin for jenkins, i am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Couldn't read generated build info at : /tmp/generated.build.info9054669860133637092.json
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.model.Run$RunnerAbortedException
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.Utils.getGeneratedBuildInfo(Utils.java:188)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.ArtifactoryMavenBuild$Execution.run(ArtifactoryMavenBuild.java:109)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.ArtifactoryMavenBuild$Execution.run(ArtifactoryMavenBuild.java:75)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousStepExecution.start(AbstractSynchronousStepExecution.java:40)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:184)
```

My Jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
def buildNo = "${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
def jarVersion = "1.0.${buildNo}" //default major version of zip artifact

node {
  // checkout from source
  stage 'Checkout'
  checkout scm

  // release using the Jenkins Artifactory plugin. Jenkins buildNo is used as release version
  stage 'Create Release & Deploy to Artifactory'

  // get artifactory server from global config
  def server = Artifactory.server('artifactory')

  // maven build - plugin auto deploys the build artifact to the specifid repo
  def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
  rtMaven.tool = 'M3'
  rtMaven.deployer server: server, releaseRepo: 'libs-release-local', snapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot-local'
  def buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'clean install -DreleaseVersion=' + jarVersion

  //finally publish build info
  server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
}
```

The problem seems to happen at the `rtMaven.run` stage of the pipeline. Has anyone seen this when using the artifactory plugin with maven?

The strange thing is the issue doesn't happen all the time, it's intermittent. I am running Jenkins inside Openshift (Kubernetes) as well so the jenkins slave is running as a docker container and not persisting any build state across build versions.

Comment: We're currently working on a fix for this issue. Will publish a fix soon.

Comment: There's a snapshot version of the Jenkins Artifactory that includes a fix for this issue. The snapshot was created on top of version 2.8.2. The link is available as a comment in this Jira issue: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-862